# Google Sheets/Regex - How to pull all numbers that start with #

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet cell that reads:

```
Ticket No. #3223
Ticket No. #2334
Ticket No. #4005
```

Is there a way to pull all numbers starting with #, but not include the #?
Results Example:

```
 3223
 2334
 4005
```

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can just use this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\D+)(\d+)","$2"&char(10))
```

The parenthesis are a `capture group` so what I am doing is saying replace all non-digits `\D+` in the first capture group, with all digits `\d+` in the second capture group. The `CHAR(10)` at the end is what gives you a new line.

If you actually want them in separate cells you can change the `&char(10)` to a `;` and then use split and transpose to stack them:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\D+)(\d+)","$2;"),";"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly, though, it appears this only selects the first number, instead of all 3

Comment: I didn't realize they were all in a single cell - one second ill update it